# Unable to create secret for "Bot Channel Registration"

Tags: botframework

I created one "Bot Channel Registration" resource on Microsoft Azure Portal, I am now trying to create a secret for the resource, however, I get an error " The application was not found. If the application was just created, wait a few minutes and refresh the page. [dTpaM]", I even waited 2 hours but still, I was unable to create a secret for this resource. Any idea how can I resolve this?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? If @pravandan-chand steps helped, please mark that as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Azure Portal, then click on Azure Active Directory ( left hand pane ) ,then click on App registrations ( not the Legacy option ) then click on Owned Applications and then select the relevant application.

Then click on Certificates and Secret and then click on New Client Secret, fill the relevant details and then you can use this newly created Secret.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it with a kind of a workaround.

1. Go to Azure Portal and expand left panel

[image]

2. Click `Azure Active Directory`

[image]

3. Type and select `App registrations`

[image]

4. Click `View all applications..` and select you App
   [image]
5. Click `Certificates & secrets`

[image]